# Multitenant per schema in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I decided to use postgresql with my multitenant app per schema.
I need to create new schema for each customer.

My plan is to have `tenant` table in `public` schema with `tenant_name` and `schema_name`.

1. Tenant A, tenanta
2. Tenant B, tenantb

I need this to have control over schemas and for listing schemas. I want to use liquibase and run migrations for all schemas except public.

I implemented multitenant provider, resolver, context, filter but it works only if I add schema annotation to Entity class

I tried to create similar table in all customers like

```
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product
...
```

even for public (just for testing) to be sure it is in every schema.

and it tells me that column does not exist.

Won’t it work without scheme annotation? Problem is I need this table (and more) for all schemas except public..
how should I handle it? Anyone?

**MY CODE**

I created tenant table with annotations

```
@Table(name = "tenant", schema = "public")
public class Tenant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String tenant;
    private String schema;
}
```

I also implemented multitenant provider

```
@Component
public class MultitenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public MultitenantConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getConnection("public");
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.setSchema("public");
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class<?> unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, this);
    }
}
```

resolver

```
@Component
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
    private final String DEFAULT_TENANT = "public";
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String tenant = MultitenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(tenant)) {
            return DEFAULT_TENANT;
        }
        return tenant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
    }
}
```

and context

```
public class MultitenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CURRENT_TENANT = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        return CURRENT_TENANT.get();
    }

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
        CURRENT_TENANT.set(tenant);
    }
}
```

I have a tenant filter too.

Comment: You have a `tenant` table but forget to query it for the schema. Looks like you are setting the `tenant_name` and not the schema, hence it won't work as that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

@M.Deinum I even don't use `tenant` table for now. This is a place I want to have an info about all tenants.

I use a tenant filter

```
@Order(1)
public class TenantFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        MultitenantContext.setCurrentTenant("alliance");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I also create a service to add new tenant

```
@Service
public class TenantSchemaService {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public TenantSchemaService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, TenantRepository tenantRepository) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void createSchema(String name) {
            String query = "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS " + name;
            jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
            runLiquibase(name);
    }

    public void runLiquibase(String schema) {
        try (Connection connection = Objects.requireNonNull(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).getConnection();
             Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
        ) {
            database.setDefaultSchemaName(schema);
            new Liquibase("db/master/changelog.yaml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database).update("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 schemas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX1o9.png)